# What is scope of temp table when called by nested stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is two part question:

1. I have two stored procedures: sp1 & sp2.  If sp1 creates a temp table #temp then executes sp2 will I have access to #temp in the nested procedure?  If not, how to do it in another way?
2. Can a function accept a parameter of type table? I tried but SQL Server give me an error. Why this can't work? Maybe sqlserver should support something like Generic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes, the temp table is in the scope of the connection, so the nested stored procedure (sp2) will have access to #temp table create in sp1.
2. Yes, in SQL 2008 we have ability to pass a table valued parameter (TVP) as input to a function or stored procedure. You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

It works to access a temp table in child procedures, it must be declared in parent.

```
CREATE PROC test2
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpchild
    SELECT 100
END

CREATE PROC [dbo].[TEST]
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tmpchild (id int)
    
    EXEC test2;
    
    SELECT * FROM #tmpchild;
END
```

When you run the `TEST` SP, which calls `test2`, `#tempchild` is accessible in the child SP (`test2`).

And it gives below output:

```
100
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. I was skeptical at first but this ended up saving me a lot of problems - I wish I could upvote it +10.

Comment: @SQLServerSteve you can now, if have not :)

Answer (score 1):

This example works :

Temp table of a procedure is accessible in nested procedure

```
alter procedure tests2 (@tmptbl varchar(20))
as
    declare @sql as nvarchar(1000)
    set @sql = 'select * from ' + @tmptbl
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    print @tmptbl
go

alter procedure tests1
as
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpchild'))
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmpchild END
    create table #tmpchild(id int)
    insert into #tmpchild(id) values(100)
    exec tests2 '#tmpchild'
go


exec tests1
```

Answer (score 1):

Temparary Table can be accessed in the Child SP when called from Parent SP as temp table is in the scope of the connection. Please see below code for reference.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ParentSP   
AS
BEGIN
    --Assuming, there is a pre-existing 'Employee' table in DB
    select * INTO #TempTable FROM Employee   --temparary table created here
    EXEC ChildSP
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE ChildSP    
AS
BEGIN
    (select COUNT(1) as Count FROM #Temp)
    select * FROM #TempTable --tempary table assessed here
END
GO

EXEC ParentSP
```

Comment: I appreciate your example but where is Employee table, can you please add it as well

Comment: @programtreasures : I have added a comment that 'Assuming there is Employee' table in the db. Please create one and you won't have issue in the solution.